# Python: How can I manipulate csv data in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have created a list which has the totality of all the data in the csv file.
How do I seperately call upon data in rows and columns?

For instance:

```
   **a,  b  ,c** 
**1**  a1  b1  c1
**2**  a2  b2  c2
```

How can I identify a single cell within the list?

Comment: Are you using Numpy / Pandas?

Comment: No, and I cannot as well.

Comment: We don't know how your data looks.  You say you have it in a list, is this a list for each row?  Can you post an example?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Comment: @KindStranger I want to make a list for each row AND each column. Then I want to be able to call upon the data. For instance, I have a csv file with item_id, name, price, location. I want all this in a list, so I can use functions to call upon the data from within the csv file. For instance, I want a function that shows me the name, price and location of a product when I type in the item_id.

Comment: @YousufFarhan sounds like you want a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 1):

try below code:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c','1','a1', 'b1', 'c1', '2', 'a2', 'b2','c2']
columns = 3
result = list(zip(*[iter(l[columns:])]*(columns+1)))
result2 = {i[0]:i[1:] for i in result}
item_id = '2'
result2[item_id]
```

output:

```
 ('a2', 'b2', 'c2')
```

or you could try below code:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c','1','a1', 'b1', 'c1', '2', 'a2', 'b2','c2']
columns = 3
item_id = '2'
index = l.index(item_id)
l[index:index+columns]
```

output:

```
['a2', 'b2', 'c2']
```